# Cannot get url parameters when reloadin to same page

Tags: reactjs, parameters, react-router, query-string

I am trying to reload my route /dashboard with some added parameters. here's my code(similar)

```
componentWillMount(){
  const query = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
  console.log(query);
}
render(){
  onChange = (value) => {
    var search = queryString.stringify(...value);
    history.push(`/dashboard/${search}`);
  }
}
```

So i get the parameters on the url but the page doesn't reload. So I cannot get the parameters value on my componentWillMount.

What am i doing wrong? Please help me